# Use pkg-config to test the version on an installed program?

Tags: linux, package-management, autotools

I am working from a shell script (and not an Autotools script). According to the `pkg-config(1)` man page, *"Return meta information about installed libraries"*. For example, here is a check of Nettle 3.4 installed in `/usr/local`:

```
$ pkg-config --exists --print-errors "nettle >= 3.1"
$ echo $?
0
```

When I try to check Autoconf it returns an error. This is expected based on the man page:

```
$ pkg-config --exists --print-errors "autoconf >= 2.63"
Package autoconf was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `autoconf.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'autoconf' found
```

Is it possible to use `pkg-config` to test non-library packages? If not, is there a similar tool to supply information about installed programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pkg-config` tool is primarily used for querying what compiler and linker flags should be used when compiling and linking with a specific library package, while at the same time possibly asserting a specific version of said package.

The `autoconf` software does not provide an `autoconf.pc` file for `pkg-config`, because it does not provide headers or libraries that another program may use (similarly for `automake`).

Depending on what package manager your Linux uses, you may possibly use that (or some tool related to it, for example `dpkg-query` on Debian-based systems) to query for the status of installed packages.

Comment: Thanks. The distro's package tools won't help in this case because I need to know the version of the tool returned from `command -v`. The scripts I have are building software from sources on machines like OS X 10.5 and Solaris 10. The new software goes into `/usr/local`.

Comment: @jww Umm... Why did you tag the question with "Linux" then? Also, not all utilities provide a -v option to get its version. It is further unclear now what you intend to use pkg-config for. Is it for building the software you're mentioning, or for something else?

Comment: The question was tagged Linux for two reasons. First it includes old Linux systems. Second, they are GNU tools being installed by the build scripts.

Comment: Sorry it was not clear. I wanted to use `pkg-config` because I don't want to write my own script to do the same job as `pkg-config`. For example, when building Git we can include libunistring *iff* Autoconf is >= 2.62. So I need to test the Autoconf  version to determine if I should add `--with-unistring` to Git's configure options.